# How does multi-core Intel Turbo Boost work?

Tags: cpu, performance, clockspeed, turbo-boost, intel

I have a Linux laptop with Intel [i5-8250u](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/124967/intel-core-i58250u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz/specifications.html) on it, and the Intel CPU support Intel Turbo Boost. With some reaserch it looks like you can acually Turbo Boost all the cores at the same time, but you can't boost all cores to the max turbo clock frequency, in my case the max turbo frequency is `3.4 Ghz` and even when the CPU is under 100% usage the 4 cores are just in `2.2 Ghz`. So here is the problem, what is limiting the 4 cores to all get to the max tubo boost frequency `3.4 Ghz`? Will increasing TDP help?

Comment: on windows there was recently a similar problem, and the solution was to set the power settings profile to max speed

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/87610/does-intel-turbo-boost-work-in-ubuntu & https://blog.christophersmart.com/2017/02/08/manage-intel-turbo-boost-with-systemd/

Comment: it does not answer the quastion of "will increase max TDP fix it?"

Comment: TDP isn't a setting though?

Comment: Please do not create a new account if your old one is blocked from asking questions.

Comment: What prevents it is power usage (chip burnout), power supply (motherboard burn out and heat building up (TPD, stopping it long-term but not nessecary short term).  Also, not all cores might boost to max, but on Intel this max seems to be on all cores and thus not relevant.  (AMD does use 'best' cores, which is more efficient, but does imply that not all core might boost to max)

Comment: Having said that. 1. Yes, use one account please.   2. In a laptop cooling might be an additional limit (though I write this from a laptop with a delidded CPU, thick copper heatspreader, liqued metal 'paste', ....   It is not cost efficient though)