# does intel TDP-UP effect performance?

Tags: cpu, performance, overclocking, intel

I got a linux laptop with i5 8250u which got max tdp of 25w and normal tdp of 15w, after some reserch I found that if you decrease the tdp of a cpu it's going to get slower. But consider this, if you increase the tdp of a cpu, for example in my case from 25 to 35, will it be faster? I'm sure increase tdp is posible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This question is closely related to this other question: ... https://superuser.com/questions/1780711/how-does-multi-core-intel-turbo-boost-work

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20overclock

Comment: Whether any of these things are adjustable is determined by your laptop firmware and that firmware is written by your manufacturer. If you require more CPU power then you should get a more powerful machine.

Comment: It will get hotter, and you'll have to get that heat out of the system somehow.